# Where do iOS app bug reports go?

Tags: support, ios-app

The email I received concerning the iOS alpha app said to post bug reports and related questions in Meta Stack Overflow but in the app, it says to use Meta Stack Exchange for reports. Which is the correct meta site?

Comment: Use [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) since it is related to all Stack Exchange sites in general.

Comment: FYI - this is not a duplicate.  Per the link in the accepted answer, bug reports (or any question) for the iOS app (and android app) belong on MSE, not on a child meta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The iOS App deals with the entire SE network of sites, and any bug reports you have are relevant to the entire network of users across sites who use the app.

Hence, the [ios-app tag on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-app) is the appropriate place to post such reports.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I do see more tags on MSE